# PHP Database Class query Fatal error

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, fatal-error

Folks,

Let me preface this by stating that I'm trying to learn OOP so rather than use one of the existing Mysqli abstraction layers out there, I wanted to write my own Class.

I have the class defined in a file, and I'm just trying to get a generic query working before I start writing specific query functions.

```
<?php

/* Database Config */
define('DB_NAME', 'project');
define('DB_USER', 'foo');
define('DB_PASS', 'bar');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1');


class Database {

  private $host;
  private $user;
  private $pw;
  private $db;
  public $con;

  public function __construct($hostname, $user, $pass, $db) {
    $this->DB_HOSTNAME = $hostname; 
    $this->DB_USER = $user;
    $this->DB_PASS = $pass;
    $this->DB_NAME = $db;

  }

   public function connect() {
        $this->con = new mysqli($this->hostname, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db)
            or die('Database unavailable');
        $this->con->set_charset ('utf8');
    } 

    public function query($sql) {
        $stmt = $this->con->query($sql);
    }

}

// Create a single global instance of the database class
global $DB;
$DB = new Database();
?>
```

Then I created a simple test.php containing:

```
<?php

include_once("include/config.inc");

if ($DB) {
$sql = "select user_login, user_name from users where 1 order by user_name, user_login";
$stmt = $DB->query($sql) or die($DB->errno.__LINE__);
$result = $stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

var_dump($result);
}
else die('Database Unavailable');

?>
```

When I call that page I get

**Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /www/htdocs/project/include/db.class.php on line 33**

I'm not getting a die from the test page, so I believe it can reach the database, and I know the table holds data and the query works because if I switch to non Class based DB definition I get an array with expected data.

So I'm pretty sure it's a problem I created in the Class, I just can't figure out what it is.  Advice please?

Answer (score 0):

Seems your object wasn't created

this is your construct. It means when you create object you need to specify parameters

```
public function __construct($hostname, $user, $pass, $db)
```

Do it like this

```
$DB = new Database('hostname', 'dbuser', 'dbpass', 'db');
```

Comment: Mind expanding your answer to show context to where you're creating the new object?  if I do it within the class, I get ` PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes)` if I do it outside of the class where I'm declaring it as a global I still get the non object error originally mentioned.

Comment: Run $DB->connect() after class initialization

Answer (score 0):

Your class is initialized fine, that's not the issue. The issue is that it can't find the query function on con, since you're not calling connect before you call query.

You should add a line inside your query function to call connect if con doesn't yet exist or isn't active, so you don't have to remember to call it before calling query.